# How to clone and post event to another window

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying have a better understanding of wxpython management, and tried the following code.

What I basically want to do is catching an event, clone it, and send it to another control, for the same event to happen on two different windows.

The event is sent correctly to the second TextCtrl (t2), but don't seem to be further processed as no text.
What is wrong in my way to process ?

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY):
        super().__init__(parent, id)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.t1 = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.t2 = wx.TextCtrl(self)

        self.t1.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)
        self.t2.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey2)

        sizer.Add(self.t1)
        sizer.Add(self.t2)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnKey(self, event):
        print("Event %s on t1 occured" % event.ClassName)
        e2 = event.Clone()
        wx.PostEvent(self.t2, e2)
        event.Skip()

    def OnKey2(self, event):
        print("Event %s from t1 received" % event.ClassName)
        event.Skip()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        super().__init__(parent, id, 'Events')
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What is your use case? You can bind multiple controls to the same event handler? I can't think of a good reason to do this

Comment: Well, actually, I'm trying to transfer a wheelmouse event from a TextCtrl to a ListCtrl (I'm trying to build a custom widget). I managed to do this with with the scroll method, but I have to calculate the scroll value from the wheelmouse event, and found it more convenient to directly pass the event. I plunged deep in the Events documentation, and tried to fully understand the mechanism, and thus came to this simple case...

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing, re-route scrollwheel events to my ListCtrl (report mode), and it seems like the value returned by `GetWheelRotation` is already in pixels - i.e. there's no calculation required in figuring out the scroll amount! I haven't seen this supported anywhere in the documentation, and I don't have any idea if this is universal,  but I've go this code in place on my Frame __init__:

```
    self.itemList = wx.ListCtrl(self.mainPanel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.OnMouseWheel)
```

and later in the my Frame class:

```
def OnMouseWheel(self, evt):
    #print "OnMouseWheel"
    r = evt.GetWheelRotation()
    self.itemList.ScrollList(0, -r)
    evt.Skip()
```

and I seem to scroll the same number of lines regardless of whether the ListControl or the Frame handles the event. (The negative sign is there to make the scroll-wheel scroll the list in the directions I prefer. It might not be the conventional way or the way *you* prefer.)

So I wouldn't put this in some major product, but it's working just fine for my small project. Thought I'd post the code to show how easy it ended up being.